# can I redirect to thank you page?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, payment

I'm using the Payments API via the Javascript SDK.  After the user has completed payment, I want to redirect to a thank you page within FB.  I understand that redirect_uri is limited to the site defined in the FB App setup.  So how do I do this?  Or does FB consider their popup dialog to be the final thank you page and that's all that's allowed?

```
   function buy() {
     var credits= 2;
     FB.ui({
         method: 'pay',
         credits_purchase: false,
         order_info: credits,
         // FB says it will only redirect to the URL registered for the app.
         // I'll try to fudge  by adding a parameter:
         redirect_uri:'https://apps.facebook.com/MYAPP/index.php?thankyou=1',
         dev_purchase_params: {
             oscif: true
          }
       },
       function(response) {
         div = document.getElementById('fb-response');
         div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do redirect manually, e.g.

```
function(response) 
{
    window.location = "https://apps.facebook.com/MYAPP/index.php?thankyou=1";
})
```

or after sending request

```
function(response) 
{
    div = document.getElementById('fb-response');
    div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
});
window.location = "https://apps.facebook.com/MYAPP/index.php?thankyou=1";
```